# Tooltip text formatting : *Making partly bold*

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

Issue: I want to make Tooltip text Partly bold.

Example text that i want to show on tooltip:

label1: **label1Value**

label2: **label2Value**

Progress so far: I have made a custom tooptip class with my own implementation of Draw event. I have used:

```
DrawToopTipEventArgs newAgrs = new DrawToopTipEventArgs (
    e.Graphics, e.AssociatedWindow, e.AssociatedControl, 
    e.Bounds, e.ToolTipText, this.BackColor, this.ForeColor,
    new Font("Arial Unicode MS", 8.25F, FontStyle.Bold));

newAgrs.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
```

Main Issue: This way  am able to make complete tooltiptext bold, but still stuck how i can make only the value part bolds and keep rest of the labels as it is. (as shown above).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to measure your text and draw everything yourself.

```
private void ToolTip_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    using (var boldFont = new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold))
    {
        var headerText = "Header: ";
        var valueText = "Value";

        var headerTextSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(headerText, e.Font);

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, headerText, e.Font, e.Bounds.Location, Color.Black);

        var valueTextPosition = new Point(e.Bounds.X + headerTextSize.Width, e.Bounds.Y);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, valueText, boldFont, valueTextPosition, Color.Black);
    }
}
```

I hard-coded the header and value strings for simplicity. It should be trivial to extend this to work for multiple lines. The measured text size has a height, you can also get the height from the `Font` object itself.

The reason you're example is making everything bold is that you're just delegating all the drawing to a instance of `DrawToolTipEventArgs` with a new font and telling it to draw the tool tip text (all of it) with the new arguments. It happily took the new font and draw all the text using it.

One additional thing to keep in mind is that the `Popup` event should also be handled. That even is used to measure the size of the tooltip so you have enough room to draw your text. If you don't handle it, it may not be wide enough to handle the bold font. Specifically, you'll want to set the `PopupEventArgs.ToolTipSize` property.

Comment: Thank you it was a Perfect answer. Worked for me.

I have an additional requirement now, can you please tell if it's possible to add checkbox control to this tooltip text?

example:
label: value
[checkbox contol]

Comment: The short answer is "No". To do what you're wanting you either have to find a third-party control which allows you to have more advanced tooltips or you'll have to write something yourself using another borderless `Form`.

Comment: Now i am getting another problem. This is working fine with one datagrid entry but with multiple the rectangle box showing is mixing all the text to be displayed and showing overlapping black backgroung (something really absurd). Any idea what could be the reason?

I have handled popup event to set the e.ToolTipSize to be enough large still getting some absurd black backgrounds inserting multiple rows in datagridview.

Can you also please tell me how can can i draw background for this tooltip?

Comment: Either clear the graphics or fill a rectangle the size of the tooltip

Comment: Done that but it didn't work. In Draw tooltip event, i added DrawToolTipEventArgs.ResetClip and also did tooltip.RemoveAll() but didn't help.

Debugging gave me slight hint. When first time i hover, pop up event is raised that popup an empty tooltip window (which is correct). This window is filled in Draw event when TextRender.DrawText is called.

Issue: But when i am hovering mouse the second time, the execution of popup this time does not give an empty tooltip window but has contents from previous tooltip text and half filled with black background.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to use `DrawToolTipEventArgs.Graphics.Clear` or `DrawToolTipEventArgs.Graphics.FillRectangle`. WinForms doesn't clear the graphics context between calls to paint because it takes time to do so and you may not want to repaint the whole context.